# definition of Riemann integrability on [a, b]

Tags: real-analysis

I have this definition:

a function $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ is every extension of $f$ to $[a, b]$ is Riemann integrable. In this case, the integral on a to b does not depend on the values of the extension.

We seem to mostly apply this in the context of derivatives, since by nature, we can only differentiate on an open interval. I'm a bit confused though. Is there ever a case where we can't extend to $[a, b]$ and have it not be Riemann integrable, particularly since the value of Riemann integrability doesn't depend on finitely many points?

Answer (score 0):

Look at $f:(0,1)\to\Bbb{R}$, given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. This cannot be extended in any manner to give an integrable function on $[0,1]$ (proper Riemann integrable, or improper Riemann integrable, or Lebesgue integrable).

We can actually make things worse. In the above example, we have a definite value for the integral over, namely $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\,dx=+\infty$. But, there examples of $C^{\infty}$ functions on $(0,1)$ such that $\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx=\infty$ and $\limsup\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1f(x)\,dx=+\infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1f(x)\,dx=-\infty$, so this is a truly horrible situation.

The theorem you’re thinking about when you say “ particularly since the value of Riemann integrability doesn't depend on finitely many points?” is that if $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, and $g:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a function which equals $f$ except perhaps at finitely many points, then $g$ is Riemann-integrable and $\int_a^bf=\int_a^bg$. However, if $f$ is not yet known to be Riemann-integrable, then of course none of this matters.